# Weird Collisions in ODE

Tags: c++, collision-detection, directx9, open-dynamics-engine

I'm trying to get a basic OBB/OBB Collision System working. For this I use ODE.

My problem is: Whenever I use the `dSpaceCollide` and pass in my Space and my Callback, my Callback shows me, that a collision happened. But the contact-point is far away (or even in X/Y/Z-(Near-)Infinite) from my OBB's.

Here a pic:

[image]

I did this:

- In the Constructor: Box with `dCreateBox`
- Every frame: Position with `dGeomSetPosition` and
- Rotation with `dGeomSetRotation`
- Also every frame: Check per `dSpaceCollide`

What could I've missed? Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm using DirectX9!

**EDIT:**

My Collision-Code:

In my Game-Loop:

```
dSpaceCollide(space, 0, &nearCallback); // space is my dSpaceID
```

My NearCallback:

```
static void nearCallback(void *data, dGeomID o1, dGeomID o2)

{

dContact contact;

contact.surface.mode = dContactBounce | dContactSoftCFM;
contact.surface.mu = dInfinity;
contact.surface.mu2 = 0;
contact.surface.bounce = 0.01;
contact.surface.bounce_vel = 0.1;
contact.surface.soft_cfm = 0.01;

if (int numc = dCollide(o1, o2, 1, &contact.geom, sizeof(dContact)))
{
    // DrawTextOnScreen is a function to Draw things on my Screen (obviously)
    DrawTextOnScreen("Collision", D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0), 2, 200, 270, 20);
    DrawTextOnScreen(std::to_string(numc).c_str(), D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 2, 220, 270, 20);
    // etc...
}

else
    DrawTextOnScreen("No Collision", D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0), 2, 200, 270, 20);
}
```

**EDIT-2:**

After some trying I got to a point where the Collision not not works. :-P

I changed it this way:

The Rotation is made by Quaternions instead of Matrices. And I update the Box-Length every Frame.

Now it showes me, that there is no collision when there is no collision. (Fine) The problem is, that when there is a collision, it doesn't show it to me:

[image]

But (!) when I Spawn myself at the exact same position of the "Enemy", it detects a collision. I can rotate around the X-Axis and the Point where the collision occurs changes. The collision-point is in a weird Position.

[image]

The Box in ODE is declared with the same dimensions as I declared for the Box, which is rendered!

**EDIT-3**

I just want to show you how I define my Space!

```
// Initialization
dSpaceID space;
space = dSimpleSpaceCreate(space);

// In the Loop  
dSpaceCollide(space, 0, &nearCallback);
```

I really hope, that you can help! And apologise my english, it's kind of shitty! :-)

**EDIT-4**
After a week of so doing other stuff, I looked back on the problem and found the issue:
In the beginning you have to declare

```
dDouble
```

instead of

```
dSingle
```

...

Makes me a little bit sad :-( Somthing boring as an error... :-)

Comment: Could you post your actual collision code? Spaces are axis aligned and are used for quick rejection tests, you must then perform the actual collision tests to find the collisions. The [documentation](http://ode-wiki.org/wiki/index.php?title=Manual:_Collision_Detection#Collision_detection) is quite good over that subject.

Comment: Are you sure the box that represents the geom is at the same place that it is visually?

Comment: I think, every frame I set the position to exact the same position where my character is!

Comment: I first set the Render-Position with 'D3DXMatrixTranslate(&rotMat, coordinate.x, coordinate.y coordinate.z)' and the the collision-box with 'dGeomSetPosition(obb, coordinate.x, coordinate.y, coordinate.z)'. When the collision works I will reverse this, but for now...

Comment: And you have only one space?

Comment: Yes, only one space.

Comment: Could you make an answer out of your edit #4?